# formula for $E$($X^{2}$)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable ( values in $\mathbb{N_0}$ )

Show that:

$$ E(X^{2})= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (2k-1)P(X \ge k) $$

I already know that:

$$E(X^{2}) = E(X(X-1)) + E(X) $$

$$ E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X \ge k)  $$

Maybe this could help?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) may be useful. (Though Michael Lee's suggestion seems to be the more natural/straightforward route to take.)

Answer (score 4):

$$E(X^2) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^2 P(X = n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n (2k- 1)P(X = n).$$

Now try reversing the sums.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X^2\geq k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X\geq \lceil \sqrt{k}\rceil)$$ as $X$ only takes integer values. Then, \begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X\geq \lceil \sqrt{k}\rceil) &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=(i-1)^2+1}^{i^2} \mathbb{P}(X\geq \lceil \sqrt{k}\rceil) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=(i-1)^2+1}^{i^2} \mathbb{P}(X\geq i) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} [i^2-((i-1)^2+1)+1]\cdot \mathbb{P}(X\geq i) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (2i-1)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X\geq i) \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Note that for a suitable $f:\Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ holds with Fubini:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^nf(n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Bbb{1}_{\{k\leq n\}} f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb{1}_{\{k\leq n\}} f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty f(n)$$